# Dealing with text/plain in iron-ajax and dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer, iron-ajax

I have an API which unfortunately returns `text/plain` elements. Although the output format is JSON, the mime type is `text/plain`.

When using `iron-ajax` to request output from the API, I can store the output in a String called `response`. However, I cannot iterate through the output, which is a list of json objects of the like

```
[ {"userid": 1, "name": "testuser"}, {"userid": 2, "name": "testuser 2"}]
```

since dom-repeat complains that this object is not an array.

I tried to dom-repeat using certain additional function, for example:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response.values()}}">
```

or

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{Array.from(response)}}">
```

but these functions return nothing. How can I deal with my text/plain data in dom-repeat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you received the response in `String` format you may convert to `JSON.Parse(string)` and the format you provided above is exacly format which dom-repeat needs.

here this below link, you may check. (You can even debug the console)

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/NyaNxo)